# Tuple (key, value) to dictionary ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a string that I regex which returns me a tuple (see results printed) and I want to create a dictionary from it (first entry of tuple is key, second is value), which according to StackOverflow posts should work like a charm. The for loop can return multiple points which each should be added to a single dict that should be returned.

Code & Error:

```
import re as re

n = nuke.selectedNode()
k = n.knob('scene')
script = k.toScript().replace('\n','').split('scenegraph {')

for sgrph in script:
    for m in [re.match(r".*\bname '([Point\d]+)'.*\btransform ([0-9.e+\- ]+)",sgrph)]:
        if m is not None:
            print m.groups()
            items = dict(m.groups()) #this causes the error
            print "........."
print items
```

Output:

```
# Result: ('Point1', '1.983990908e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 1.983990908e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 1.983990908e+00 0.000000000e+00 5.610483289e-01 6.365304199e+03 4.553408813e+02 1.000000000e+00      ')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
    ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it's a good idea to be explicit. For example, you can define your dictionary before your nested `for` loops, unpack explicitly and add an item to your dictionary.

```
res = {}

for sgrph in script:
    for m in [re.match(r".*\bname '([Point\d]+)'.*\btransform ([0-9.e+\- ]+)",sgrph)]:
        if m is not None:
            key, value = m.groups()
            res[key] = value
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.That's a clean and working method of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Dict in python can be created from the iterable of `(key, value)` pairs. But you have a flat tuple of values as a result of `m.groups()` call. You need to pick even elements of this tuple as keys and then odd elements as corresponding values and then `zip` them together:

```
values = ('foo', 'bar', 'qux', 'blah')
dict(zip(values[::2], values[1::2]))
```

Here is an example using `re.match().groups()`:

```
import re
match = re.match(r'(\d+) (\d+) (\d+) (\d+)', '12 34 56 78')
groups = match.groups()               # gives ('12', '34', '56', '78')
dict(zip(groups[::2], groups[1::2]))  # gives {'56': '78', '12': '34'}
```

**UPD:** Be aware that `zip` produces the sequence with the length truncated to the shortest length of its input. So if `m.groups()` returned odd number of elements the last value will not occur in the resulting dict.